# puppeteer equivalent of cypress contains() method

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cypress

The HTML looks like this:

```
const htmlStr = `
  <div>

    <div>
      <h1>title1</h1>
      <div>
        <a>click me<a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1>title2</h1>
      <div>
        <a>click me<a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div>
      <h1>title3</h1>
      <div>
        <a>click me<a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
`
```

I want to click the first `click me`.

With [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) I could do something as following:

```
cy.contains('div', 'title1').within(() => {
  cy.get('a').click()
})
```

For this example there's many ways to do it. But the idea is `find the nearest <div> who contains text 'title1'. And start from there, find <a> inside it`.

In [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) I would like some as following:

```
const element = await page.elementContains('div', 'title1') // <- narrow down
await element.click('a')
```

How to implement `elementContains()` functions, any ideas? Thanks!

----- update -----

To make it more clear, with `elementContains()` it could:

```
const element1 = await page.elementContains('div', 'title1')
await element1.click('a') // click first `click me`
const element2 = await page.elementContains('div', 'title2')
await element2.click('a') // click second `click me`
const element3 = await page.elementContains('div', 'title3')
await element3.click('a') // click third `click me`
```

Comment: I added a small answer. Check if it's perfect ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, these are XPath and selector equivalents (https://example.org/ happens to have a similar DOM structure):

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const [elemByXPath] = await page.$x('//div[h1[contains(., "Example Domain")]]//a');

    const elemBySelector = await page.evaluateHandle(
      () => [...document.querySelectorAll('div')]
              .find(
                div => [...div.querySelectorAll('h1')]
                         .some(h1 => h1.innerText.includes('Example Domain'))
              )
              .querySelector('a')
    );

    console.log(elemByXPath.toString());
    console.log(elemBySelector.toString());

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add extra functionalities to the `Page` easily using `prototype`. And get the specific element using [page.elementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args).

The only difference between `page.evaluate` and `page.evaluateHandle` is that `page.evaluateHandle` returns in-page object (`JSHandle`).

## Create the elementContains function

Puppeteer module exports the classes like this. You can extend their functionalities as you wish.

```
// extract the Page class
const { Page } = require("puppeteer/lib/Page");
```

Normally the `page` you create will become `this` inside the prototype. `page.evaluateHandle` will become `this.evaluateHandle`.

```
/**
 * @name elementContains
 * @param {String} selector specific selector globally search and match
 * @param {String} text filter the elements with the specified text
 * @returns {Promise} elementHandle
 */
Page.prototype.elementContains = function elementContains(...args) {
  return this.evaluateHandle((selector, text) => {
    // get all selectors for this specific selector
    const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    // find element by text
    const results = elements.filter(element => element.innerText.includes(text));
    // get the last element because that's how querySelectorAll serializes the result
    return results[results.length-1]; 
  }, ...args);
};
```

## Create the .get function

Now that we got our awesome `elementContains`, it's time to get the `get` function.

```
/**
 * Replicate the .get function
 * gets an element from the executionContext
 * @param {String} selector
 * @returns {Promise} 
 */
const { JSHandle } = require("puppeteer/lib/JSHandle");
JSHandle.prototype.get = function get(selector) {
  // get the context and evaluate inside
  return this._context.evaluateHandle(
    (element, selector) => {
      return element.querySelector(selector);
    },
    // pass the JSHandle which is itself
    this,
    selector
  );
};
```

## Have fun with the new function

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html); // your specified html text

  // get the element
  const elem = await page.elementContains('div', 'title1')

  // use it like any other normal element, click it, eval it, remove it etc.
  const content = await elem.$eval('h1', e=>e.innerText);
  console.log(content) // prints "title1"

  // OR use the built in click function
  const btn = await page.$('a', elem); // <-- pass the handle here
  await btn.click();

  // OR use our .get function to get another element
  const targetBtn = await elem.get('a');
  targetBtn.click(); // click it
})();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I wonder why this is not considered as accepted answer, can anyone exponential and open my mind please?

Comment: Seem `elementContains()` won't work as expected. It use `querySelectorAll('div')` to find all nodes. The root node (in this case the root <div>) will match, as `rootDiv.innerText.includes('title1')` is true. @Md. Abu Taher

Comment: Your question does mention nearest, but nearest to what? I tested the function, it worked for all given input as provided. If it doesn't work, then feel free to reply with error log.

Comment: Sorry @Md. Abu Taher if I didn't express myself clearly. For example, `const elem2 = await page.elementContains('div', 'title2')`  and `const content2 = await elem2.$eval('h1', e => e.innerText)`. Now `content2` should be `title2`, but it actually is `title1`

Comment: I see. It seems a very small bug. Maybe one or two line should be changed.

Comment: Does the accepted answer work as mentioned in above comment?

Comment: I updated the question, now it will return the last element that contains the specified text.